# Python: How to display the original color from binary image using matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np             
import matplotlib as mpl
from PIL import Image

iFile = "Temp.txt" # Binary image
shape = (320,240) # length and width of the image
dtype = np.dtype('<u2') # unsigned 16 bit little-endian.
oFile = "Temp_Main.png"

#Open binary image to convert as an image
fid = open(iFile, 'rb')

data = np.fromfile(fid, dtype)
image = data.reshape(shape)
imgplot = plt.imshow(image)
imgplot = plt.axis("off")
plt.savefig(oFile)


im = Image.open('C:/Users/sesa627732/Documents/_Cases/Temp_Main.png')

#show 90 degree flipped image
im = im.transpose(Image.ROTATE_270)

#Show vertically flipped image
im = im.transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)
im.save("Temp_Main.png")

im.show()
```

Comment: Please describe what you want to achieve. What results do you want to achieve? Do you have any example data?

Comment: I have the Temp.txt that it's a binary image... I'm  trying to convert to the original image with the original colors but I'm having only a purple and yellow color for theTemp_Main.png as a results.